# materials won't properly add to faces in blender 2.81

Tags: materials

Adding material to a face causes the face to disappear and something comes pointing out.

[image]

Comment: Please attach your blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 0):

Try it in an older version of blender. This could happen because the graphic card might not have supported the new version of the blender.

Update of driver might work.

Comment: works fine in 2.80 drivers up to date newest versions of 2.81 & 2.82 card ATI RADON 5570 drivers up to date

Comment: works with updated driver